# Trouble with storing an array permanently

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to store tasks in an array permanently for a user in my basic checklist app for iOS  (the task to be added to the checklist is entered into a UITextField) like this:

```
var list: [String] = [String]()

@IBOutlet weak var itemField: UITextField!

@IBAction func addItemPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    let task: String? = itemField.text

    list?.append(task!)

    itemField.text = nil

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(list, forKey: "list")

    let storedList = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("list")! as! NSArray

    print(storedList)

}
```

However when the stored array prints to the console it only contains the tasks entered from that instance of running the program.

For example if I enter: "Finish the dishes" into the textfield the array printed to the console will contain the text. However when I restart the program the array is empty.

My knowledge of NSUserdefaults is limited as I am mostly still a beginner therefore my logic is most likely just incorrect. I would greatly appreciate it if you know of a better way to store objects or would be able to correct me. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do you mean store it into list? If the `storedList` doesn't contain the values at startup then I wouldn't be able add it to `list` anyway though right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you aren't loading the stored list data into `list` at app startup.  Then when `addItemPressed` is called, you store the item into the empty `list` and then overwrite whatever was stored in `NSUserDefaults`.

You need to load the stored data at app startup.  You could do this is `viewDidLoad`:

```
list = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("list") as? [String] ?? []
```

This will load the previously stored value in `NSUserDefaults` into your `list` property or initialize it to an empty array if there is no such list stored in `NSUserDefaults`.